# Using ElasticSearch to find trends

Tags: elasticsearch, trend, trending

I have implemented elastic search for my search and have a good feeling it could easily be leveraged for finding trends , but its a the tip of my tongue how one would start to go about such a thing. Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me some keywords to look into further that might make this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you want to do exactly, it might be usefull to have a look at the [Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) in Elasticsearch?

If you e.g. combine the [Significant Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html) with a query for a given time frame, you will get back the terms, which are common in the given time frame, but rather unusual for the rest of the dataset (basically the trends in your dataset).